# Unable to detect a live inspection service. To enable live inspections, restart the device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-arctic-fox, layout-inspector

Anybody who has had same problem with android studio and found a solution please share solution. Android Studio Version:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 27, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
Windows 10 10.0
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 12
Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: Lombook Plugin, com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.jetbrains.kotlin, com.google.mad-scorecard, org.intellij.plugins.markdown
```

**Unable to detect a live inspection service. To enable live inspections, restart the device**

[image]

Comment: Restarting the device and reconnecting did the job.

Comment: any solution ? I'm having the same error on electric eel

Comment: This was working fine for me in AS Electric Eeel, until I introduced com.google.accompanist:accompanist-navigation-animation:0.29.1-alpha following https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/animations-in-navigation-compose-36d48870776b. Then I saw this error, regardless of which emulator or phyiscal device I use.